# ASP clássico fora do IIS? Windows x64

Tags: windows, lado-do-servidor, iis, asp, 64-bits

Alguém conhece alguma programa/server capaz de rodar o asp clássico (VBScript, JScript)

e que não seja o IIS ?

Comment: Porque não pode ser o IIS?

Comment: a maquina q possuo não tem acesso/permisão para o IIS.

Comment: Você pode tentar o IIS Express. É como uma versão portátil do IIS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando o  IIS Express (dica do @OnoSendai).
Tive da fazer alguma adapatações pq minha maquina é x64.

1. Fiz o downlaod http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038
2. Instalei o IIS
3. Fiz o download https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ da versão 32 bits
4. Instalei o Connector/ODBC do Mysql
5. Executei `c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe`
6. Crie a fonte de dados ODBC para mynha conexão mysql.
7. Configurei o site com o comando no terminal

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress /path:C:\myApp\ /port:1234

Acessei na url `http://localhost:1234/`

Tudo funcionando perfeitamente.

---

### Update:

Para facilitar em fazer com que o site rode, crie um arquivo

`run.bat`

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>"
iisexpress /path:C:\myApp\ /port:1234
```

Agora, toda vez que preciso do site dou 2 click's no arquivo acima e pronto,

o site já está online

Comment: Que bom saber que funcionou! A dica do Filipe é boa também, caso você tenha restrições de instalação.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [Utildev Cassini](http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/).

Usei durante muito tempo aqui e não tive problemas.

Ou então o iis express [embutido em um pen drive](http://leekelleher.com/2011/01/15/umbraco-on-usb-usin-iis-express-and-sqlce4/), mas aí você vai ter que configurar sempre que usar, trabalhoso, mas se for a melhor alternativa, vale a pena mencionar.

Answer (score 3):

### Utilize [Apache ASP](http://www.apache-asp.org/)

Mas ele somente roda o asp clássico, e pode ser utilizado em um linux.

Comment: ASP rodando em Linux... Até arrepiei! Hahaha

Comment: Pelo que entendi ele só aceita scripts em Perl... Acho pouco provável que alguém desenvolva algo em ASP sem usar VBScript

Comment: Só a título de curiosidade, ainda faço manutenção de vários (vários mesmo) aplicativos ASP usando JScript. Tudo rodando em um IIS no Windows Server 2003. :)

Comment: Bom, nesse caso você não utiliza os recursos do servidor, somente do cliente. Para utilizar recursos do servidor, é necessário utilizar uma linguagem que o servidor entenda, VBScript ou Perl [pelo contexto da questão].